# React.js: setState overwriting, not merging

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to React.JS and I am in the process of experimenting by building a masonry-style layout.

I render each element to the DOM, then I need to loop over each item and apply x and y positions based on the preceding elements.

The initial model looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "The Forrest",
    "description": "some cool text",
    "imgSmallSrc": "/img/img4-small.jpg",
    "imgAlt": "Placeholder image",
    "tags": [
        "Design",
        "Mobile",
        "Responsive"
    ],
    "date": 1367154709885,
    "podStyle": {
      "width": 253
    }
  }
]
```

(I've only shown one item to keep things short).

Once I complete the loop and have my x and y data I want to apply this to the `podStyle` object. I call `setState()` with the following data:

```
[
  {
    "podStyle": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "height": 146,
      "width": 253
    }
  }
]
```

This seems to remove all current data from the model and leave me with just the `podStyle` data. Am I misunderstanding how this merge works?

Comment: Try the [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) in React's addons for a declarative way of modifying complex state objects.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If your state is an object:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return { x: 0, y: 0 };
}
```

you can use `setState` to set individual keys on that object:

```
this.setState({ x: 1 }); // y still == 0
```

React does no intelligent merging of your state; for example, this does not work:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    point: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    radius: 10
  };
}

this.setState({point: {x: 1}});
// state is now == {point: {x: 1}, radius: 10} (point.y is gone)
```

[Edit]

As mentioned by @ssorallen, you can use [the immutability helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) to get the effect you're after:

```
var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, {
  point: { x: {$set: 10} }
});
this.setState(newState);
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/HW6w5/) for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/HW6w5/

Comment: So I'm pretty sure I'm setting the state as per your second example, however, 'radius' in this case is getting removed. When I'm home tonight I'll have a play around and make sure I'm setting correctly. Thanks for your help Brandon!

Comment: @DanV Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate the code in my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/HW6w5/ I also added a button to use the immutability helpers mentioned by ssorallen, which does what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Brandon. This definitely sent me in the right direction. I ended up using the $merge helper as my model was slightly different and I was also applying the updates to several children items. Works nicely though.

Answer (score 23):

> The merging is shallow, so `this.setState({point})` leaves (ed: this.state.radius) intact, but completely replaces (ed: this.state.point).
>
> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

To offer an ES7+ perspective on the answers already given, using [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) instead of `Object.assign()`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        point: { 
            x: 0, 
            y: 0,
        },
        radius: 10,
    }

    handleChange = () => {
        this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
            point: {
                // rest operator (...) expands out to:
                ...prevState.point, // x:0, y:0,
                y: 1, // overwrites old y
            },
            // radius is not overwritten by setState
        }));
    }

    render() {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

.babelrc (also requires [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) from babel preset stage 2)

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
}
```

### Updated 2018-04-22

As @sheljohn points out (thanks!), referring to `this.state` inside `setState` is unreliable:

> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> ...
>
> To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Thank you! I think it is an amazing solution.

Comment: I am new to react, but this seems wrong; `handleChange` [should call](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) `this.setState( (prevState, props) => ({ ... // use prevState.point  }) )` instead.

Comment: OMG I can't believe, it works like charm. You saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        something: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        blah: 10
    };
}

var state = Object.assign(this.state, {
    something: Object.assign(this.state.something, { y: 50 }),
});

this.setState(state);
```

Would be better if it was recursive/deep rather than hard coding the tree, but I will leave that up to the reader :)

Comment: The outer `Object.assign` isn't really doing anything since the `something` property you're assigning still refers to the original (although mutated) object.  Also, you shouldn't mutate objects in the state directly.  It may be OK since you call `setState` anyway, but it's not clean.  Furthermore, you can supply partial updates to `setState` instead of a full state object.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more: it is definitely NOT OK to mutate `this.state` and then call `setState` with a reference to `this.state`.  This is because it will break code in `shouldComponentUpdate` that may compare the next state with the previous state (which will always be equal in this case since both are references to the same object).