# updating objects with setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I pass multiple states to `setState`? Here's an example:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    list: [],
    newFilm: {},
    searchWord: '',
    searchDetails: {}
  }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.setState({
    searchDetails:someData,
    newFilm: 'I am first text',
  })
}
```

The question is:

Is the example syntactically correct ?

Comment: That would be how you do it.

Comment: Please review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898012/react-js-setstate-overwriting-not-merging

Comment: Sorry Piotr, but how this can help me ?

Comment: I made an edit to the question, but that was a loose interpretation of what I think you meant to ask. It is still unclear though what is the problem with the current code that you posted. Is it not working correctly? Why? Is there an error? What's the current issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no syntax problem with the way you are setting state, but there could be a problem with the way you are initialising you state. You have initialized newFilm as an object state but when you set its state you are giving a string. So suppose you try to render it like `{this.state.newFilm}` it will throw you an error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).

as you can see in the snippet below, since the first time the component is rendered it sees an object where later its only a string.

To fix this try initializing you state `newFilm` as `''` or take prevention when you try to render i.e. check where it contains some data and then only render.

Also I don't see `someData` defined in your `componentDidMount` function. You need to define it before you can use it.

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    list: [],
    newFilm: {},
    searchWord: '',
    searchDetails: {}
  }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  var someData = {'name': 'abc'};
  this.setState({
    searchDetails:someData,
    newFilm: 'I am first text',
  })
},
render: function() {
  console.log(this.state.newFilm);
  return (
    <div>{this.state.newFilm}</div>
  )
}
})

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```