# multi expression ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make multiexpression for ternary operator in Javascript like this :

```
condition ? 
exp1 ; ... ; expN 
:
alternative1 ; ... ; alternativeN
```

Here my code :

```
  validateEmail && validatePassword ?
        this.setState({validateForm: true})
        this.setState({nameSubmit:"onSubmit"})
        : null
```

My console returns me an error :

> Declaration or statement expected

The javascript documentation talks about :

> Syntax :
>
> condition ? expr1 : expr2

But maybe someone has achieved the multi expression ternary operator ?

Thanks

Comment: You want to create a shortcut for "switch()" ?
Because the classic boolean condition only knews two possible outcomes. :-)

Comment: And what should it evaluate to? `exp1` or `expN` or something inbetween?

Comment: @JonasW. He's not trying to do multiple conditions, just multiple expressions in the true and false cases.

Comment: The real question is *why*? Ternary operators should be used for short conditions and results, they become unreadable if you try to put too much in them. Use `if` for anything complicated.

Comment: @JonasW. Oops, my comment was meant for JanRecker.

Comment: @JanRecker He's not looking for `switch`, he only has one condition, multiple results.

Comment: @JonasW. Notice also that his example expressions are mainly side-effecting, not value-returning. He just seems to be using the ternary as a replacement for `if`.

Comment: @barmar hence my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const exp = () => { exp1; ... ; expN }
const alt = () => { alternative1; ... ; alternativeN }

condition ? exp() : alt();
```

It's not very readable you could use an IIFE to create the function and execute it in the same line.

```
condition ? (() => { exp1; ... ; expN })() : (() => { alternative1; ... ; alternativeN })();
```

Edit: I think you just added your code. In your code, I would recommend simply merging your setState calls into one command:

```
this.setState({
  validateForm: true, 
  nameSubmit:"onSubmit"
});
```

Comment: thanks for the hints, concerning the second form with coma, my console returns me "second argument expect to be a function"

Comment: Ah, yes I needed to add an arrow function. EdIted answer

Comment: my mistake, I would mean for this.setState({
  validateForm: true, 
  nameSubmit:"onSubmit"
});

Comment: I'm positive that that line of code is acceptable, so it must be coming from elsewhere. The full line would be -----  
        validateEmail && validatePassword ?
        this.setState({ validateForm: true, nameSubmit:"onSubmit" })
        : null   ------- Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249934/updating-objects-with-setstate-in-react

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

```js
let a = 0,
    b = 1,
    c = 2,
    d = a === 0 ? (b++, c++) : -1;
    
console.log(b, c, d); // prints 2 3 and 2(because this will be the last expression to be evaluated).
```

Comment: clever.. hadn't thought of this!

Answer (score 1):

To execute multiple statements in one branch there is the `if` statement:

```
if(validateEmail && validatePassword) {
   this.setState({validateForm: true});
   this.setState({nameSubmit:"onSubmit"});
}
```